# Direction for a socially concious computer illiterate

Tags: unity

I want to speak Ubuntu but have missed the computer revolution being involved the real one please guide me to a spot where I can start a journey into the world of Ubuntu,Linux,Mozzilla .......Activism even if it's from my brand new pre-owned computer chair, very ergonomic or at least comfortable.
Please suggest my first step.Applogies for an innapropriate use of this box but eager to rejoin life.

Comment: While I upvoted this, this isn't really a question suited for this site. :(

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is ontopic here, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Ubuntu and Linux. Start by running the live / desktop CD and if it works well with your hardware and you like the interface, go ahead and install.

KDE (kubuntu) and xfce (xubuntu) and LXDE (Lubuntu) all offer a slightly different user interface, LXDE works well for older less powerful hardware (but unity 2d is not bad).

From there I would suggest you familiarize yourself with the Ubuntu community. Many people come to Ubuntu for the OS, and stay for the community.

If you are not familiar with it, irc has a thriving Ubuntu community

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat

Come on over to #ubuntu or #ubuntu-beginners (or any of the other ubuntu channels such as #ubuntu-offtopic or ##club-ubuntu).

When you have enough reputation you will be able to use some of the chat channels here as well.

In addition there are the Ubuntu Forums and Launchpad. The Forums provides support, but there is an off-topic area, The Café, for social interaction.

Launchpad is used primarily (IMO) for developers, bug reports, and ppa.

Lots of additional resources (sorry if I forgot anyone, tried to mention the major ones), see:

http://www.ubuntu.com/community

Edit: I completely forgot about the LoCo. The LoCo teams are Local community teams and often work with local LUG (Linux user groups) and, assuming you have a LoCo (or LUG) near you, make an excellent entry point.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoTeams